# SSL module is not available error in python3 Windows 11

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, importerror, pyscript

When running the FlightRadarAPI on python 3.12, windows 11 I'm getting an ImportError: **Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 499, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 340, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<exec>", line 55, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/FlightRadar24/api.py", line 309, in get_flights
    response = APIRequest(Core.real_time_flight_tracker_data_url, request_params, Core.json_headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/FlightRadar24/request.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.__response = request_method(url, headers = headers, cookies = cookies, data = data)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 769, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 295, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1060, in _new_conn
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

To add to the complexity, the code works when run normally, the error only happens while running it via [PyScript](https://pyscript.net) (a combination of python and html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL module is [unvendored by default](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html#optional-modules) in Pyodide, but can be installed in PyScript using:

```html
<py-config>
  packages=['ssl']
</py-config>
```

Once you install it, however, note that SSL generally doesn't function in browser, since [socket is not available in the browser](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/529). See also [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/140) for more discussion.